# Looking for SSMS 2008 Express Only

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I downloaded SQL Server 2008 Express from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=7593).....

But it still did not install the SQL Server Management Studio that I need to connect to my databases.....see image below....looking for this.

[image]

Where can I find the express SSMS that will work on Windowns 8 64bit?
It should be just a .msi program I need to run to get this, I have found it before years ago but cant find it again for Windows 8 and 64bit machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tick "Management Tools - Basic" during setup.

[image: Management Tools - Basic]

Complete instructions on this MSDN blog:

[Step-by-Step: Installing SQL Server Management Studio 2008 Express after Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/02/18/step-by-step-installing-sql-server-management-studio-2008-express-after-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

From "details", under the link you posted:

> Note: There are multiple files available for this download. Once you
>   click on the “Download” button, you will be prompted to select the
>   files you need.

And if you do that, you'll get the option to select these two: SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe and SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe.

If you're NOT getting the choice then try a different browser.

Comment: I did download the SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe and did the install but the actual SSMS as seen in my pic up top is no-where to be seen on my PC. It's like it installed SQL Server but not the actual Management Studio I need to connect to my SQL Server DB's. The SSMS environment.

Comment: And it's not in your Start Menu? Hit the start button, and type "SQL".. it doesn't show up?

Comment: Nope, does not show up....